# SQL query search for two strings

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a basic sql query where is search for one of two string:

1. "Nightly job up"
2. "Nightly job finished"

I have tried the where command but i getting an empty output.
This is the problematic part:

```
      where execution_location = ('Nightly job up' or Nightly job 'finished');
```

Please assist, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN(...)` instead:

```
where execution_location in ('Nightly job up', 'Nightly job finished');
```

This is the way to compare multiple values in one clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your where string should be, both for MySQL or Transact-SQL:

```
WHERE (execution_location = 'Nightly job up' OR execution_location = 'Nightly job finished');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`WHERE execution_location IN ('Nightly job up, 'Nightly job finished');`

or, if what you want is finding every string starting with Nightly job:

```
WHERE execution_location LIKE 'Nightly job%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
where execution_location in ('Nightly job up', 'Nightly job finished');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

```
('Nightly job up' or 'Nightly job finished')
```

... is evaluated as a boolean expression, and results in 0 (or `FALSE`) (because strings evaluate as `FALSE`).

Therefore your final `WHERE` clause is equivalent to:

```
... WHERE execution_location = 0
```

The right syntax has already been provided by everyone else :)